# Expected Object error in IE for downloading pdf

Tags: javascript, pdf

I have a function for downloading pdf report. I have created a seperate js file for this. The report is downloaded witout any issue in google chrome. But it is not downloaded in Internet explorer version 11. It is showing the error "Expected Object".

```js
var selectedValue = $(this).val();
         if (selectedValue == 'VesselSummary') {
          
          var $grid=$("#vessel_tab_main"); 
          var DM = $grid.pqGrid("option", "dataModel");
          var data = DM.data;
          $("#optionforvessel").empty();
          for(var i=1; i<data.length; i++){
           var newOption = document.createElement("option");
           var name=data[i].vslName;
           var index=data[i].vslId;
           
           newOption.text = name;
              newOption.value = index;
              optionforvessel.appendChild(newOption);
          }

          $("#optionforvessel").show();
         }else{
          $("#optionforvessel").hide();
}



function tpcDry(val,rowIndx){
  if(rowIndx!=0){
 vesselSubSummary.push({"selectedVslRuleName":toTitleCase(data3[val].poolRuleName)  ,"selectedVslRuleValue":data[rowIndx].tpc ,"selectedVslRulePoints":data2[rowIndx].tpcValue });
  }else{
     vesselSummaryAdditionalOne.push({"standardVslRuleName":toTitleCase(data3[val].poolRuleName),"standardVslRuleValue":data[rowIndx].tpc});
     vesselSummaryAdditionalTwo.push({"standardVslRuleName":toTitleCase(data3[val].poolRuleName),"standardVslRuleValue":data[rowIndx].tpc});
 }
 }
```

This is the code I am using. Here inside if loop function it is showing Expected Object error. Please help me How can I resolve this?

Comment: We need more code than this. We don't know what half of these variables do. Does the error say which object is "expected"? Or which line it occurs on?

Comment: I have added more code for this. here what is the error. Chrome it is working fine. IE only this problem occured.

Comment: This is still not enough code. What is `toTitleCase()`? What are `data3` and `data2`? If the error is happening inside the `tpcDry()` function, what are the values for `val` and `rowIndex` being passed in?